# Why doesn't this simple JSON encoding work?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a PHP page that generates a JSON object.
And I have a page that uses jquery library from which I want access to that object.
But it does not work. I see the message 'inside_nk' instead of 'inside_ok'. Why?
I have tried to simplify my code as possible.

prueba.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prueba.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

prueba php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

class c1 {
    var $i = 0;
    var $e = 1;
    function c1() {}
}

$inst_c1 = new c1();

echo json_encode($inst_c1);
?>
```

prueba.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert('begin');
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://[myserver]/prueba.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: '',
    success: function (data) { alert('inside_ok'); },
    error: function (data) { alert('inside_nk'); },
});
alert('end');
});
```

note:
 I tried with `"url: 'http://[myserver]/prueba.php?callback=?',"` and

```
 "dataType: 'jsonp'". 
 http://[myserver]/prueba.php
```

works. I checked with firebug.

Comment: The answer.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

I have to think another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use `json_encode` I think it would be better to use it on an `array()` rather than an object:

```
$out = array("i" => 0, "e" => 1);
echo json_encode($out);
```

Comment: I said it would be *better* to use on an `array()` not that encoding an object would fail completely. Please read my response carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have anything to do with your function being named the same thing inside its class, or you not specifying what class to access? Usually you have to do something like this:

```
// PHP 5.3
class classy{

    function classyfn(){

    }
}
$inst_c1 = new classy.classyfn();
```

Perhaps your $inst_c1 is confused as to which it is calling, or doesn't know where to find the function?

If you take out the json_encode is it outputting anything with just an echo? If not, that would point to it being a problem with the identical class and fn names.

Answer (score 0):

I think its an issue with the browser. Mine is Firefox 7.01 and its working fine.

The output obtained from the PHP (5.3.4) script is

```
{"i":0,"e":1}
```

This is valid JSON so it must not have any problem.